# problems building python distribion containing netcdf4

Tags: python, pyinstaller, netcdf

I am trying to create a python distribution using pyinstaller, without success.  The command line used is:

```
pyinstaller ^
     --paths="C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" ^
     --hidden-import="C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\netCDF4_utils.py" ^
    "C:\Users\...\Code\python\NCTSutil\NCTSU.spec"
```

The spec file used is:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\...\\Code\\python\\NCTSutil\\NCTSU.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\...\\Code\\python\\NCTSutil'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=['C:\\Users\\...\\Code\\python\\NCTSutil\\hooks'],
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='NCTSU.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='NCTSU')
```

Originally, I built the installable using only the hook path specified for the pubsub module (which I got off a web site).  When I tried running the executable I recieved the error

```
"Import error: No module named netCDF4_utils" when executable is run
```

Which I assumed was caused by the installer not being able to find some NetCDF4 dependencies. (the original package import is  "import netcdf4").

To try and solve this I tried specifying the hidden netCDF4_utils file both in the SPEC file and on the command line when running pyinstaller.  The variations of the spec file and command line and the associated errors are as follows:

1) the hidden path/file was specified in SPEC file, and the was path also given on command line.  This resulted in the error "Import error: No module named netCDF4_utils" when executable is run

2) the hidden path/file was specified on the command line but not in spec file.  This resulted in the 'compilation' error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has not attribute 'split'"

3) the hidden file (but no path) was specified on command line, and the path was given separately on the command line (the hidden file was not given in spec file).  This results in the error  "Import error: No module named netCDF4_utils" when executable is run
     .

4) The hidden file(without path) was specified on the command line (and not in spec file) which results in the error "Import error: No module named netCDF4_utils" when executable is run

5) The hidden file was specified in SPEC file and the path to the file was given on command line.  This gave a compilation error of: "NameError: name 'netCDF_util' is not defined"

I have not tried writing a hook file as I cant figure out how to write them.

If anyone has any detailed advice on how to make pyinstaller find dependent files so that they can be included in the distribution that would be greatly appreciated.

This is being done on a win7 machine using python 2.7, and pyinstaller 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It seems that there is a syntax error inside the file: `hook-netCDF4.py`
- This file is usually located inside python folder (according to your pyinstaller version):

  > C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-3.4.dev0+3c87c135a-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\hooks
- You have to open the file with a text editor and change "`netCDF4.utils`" in "`netCDF4_utils`"

The correct line inside the file should be:

```
hiddenimports = ['netCDF4_utils', 'netcdftime']
```

This solution worked for me solving the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

- remove the current `pyinstaller`: `pip uninstall pyinstaller`
- clone and install `pyinstaller` from the `python3` branch (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller)
- modify your `.spec` file from `hiddenimports = []` to `hiddenimports = ['netCDF4.utils', 'netcdftime']`

This worked for me.